# Is there a way to set position for specific layer instead of all layers on the map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

One specific layer requires the following block to be positioned properly in relation to map.

```
const mapSize = map.getSize();
const globalPos = L.DomUtil.getPosition(map.getPane("mapPane"));
const topLeft = globalPos.multiplyBy(-1);
const bottomRight = topLeft.add(mapSize);
L.DomUtil.setPosition(map.getPane(this.options.pane), topLeft);
```

This block is getting called on every map view update.

The problem is: when I try to add another layer (GeoJSON/JSON), which doesn't require such adjustment, it's also being affected by DomUtil position and is placed improperly on the map.
Is there a way to set position for specific layer only, or perhaps to offset the position of GeoJSON layer somehow to compensate for the changes to position set through DomUtil?

Comment: That is a very strange adjustment indeed. Please could you share a live [mcve] to further illustrate your situation? A sketch to explain why your 1st layer needs this specific positioning may also help.

Comment: Sorry can't do that, the case is specific to one plugin that we're using and I don't think I can recreate the scenario without it

Comment: If the plugin is public, just include it in your example. It might even be a bug that could be fixed in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly setting the position of the entire pane, set the position of individual layers by adjusting their container points allowing you to control the position of specific layers independently.

```
const customLayer = L.geoJSON(yourGeoJSONData, {
  onAdd: function (map) {
    const mapSize = map.getSize();
    const globalPos = L.DomUtil.getPosition(map.getPane("mapPane"));
    const topLeft = globalPos.multiplyBy(-1);
    const bottomRight = topLeft.add(mapSize);
    const containerPoint = map.latLngToLayerPoint(this.getLatLng());
    const adjustedContainerPoint = containerPoint.add(topLeft);
    L.DomUtil.setPosition(this.getElement(), adjustedContainerPoint);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, I found a workaround by putting the GeoJSON layer in a new pane instead of inserting it in the default pane, and since the code above only affects the default pane, the GeoJSON layer works as expected.
I know this doesn't answer the question, but it might be sufficient enough for those with the same problem.

How to create and pass new pane to GeoJSON point layer:

```
  // Pane creation    
  map.createPane("geojson");

  L.geoJson(geoData, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        // Pass pane name
        pane: "geojson",
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#FFFF00",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
      });
    }
  }).addTo(map);
```